# iOS Simulator keep debugging on the last release

Tags: debugging, ios-simulator, xamarin-studio

I was debugging using Xamarin and iOS Simulator and I had a "bug" in Xamarin Studio : the debug buttons suddenly disapear so I tried to reboot the debugger, change the debug target device, reboot Xamarin Studio and the buttons were back ! But But the compiler won't compile the changes I make in the code. So I decided to reboot my computer but the problem still persists ! I think it's because today I have compiled my code in Release mode on my device and I feel that it continues to build on the last compilation in release mode.

I didn't find any kind of problem on the web any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Going into Alpha Channels in the updates page then switching to the alpha channel, updating xamarin to 6.1 fixes the bug